# pass 2 command line arguments & display sum of both in java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I want to design a program in Java that receive the two command line arguments and display the sum of both but with some condition
Condition:
1- if user pass the value in "int" then sum comes in "int"
2- if user pass the value in "float" then sum comes in "float"
3- if user pass the value in "double" then sum comes in "double"

Note: without using if else and switch case

Output something like:

java Sum 100 50

```
    output - Sum is = 150
```

java Sum 100 50.99

```
    output - Sum is = 150.99
```

java Sum

```
    "output - Plz pass 2 command line argument as numbers (0-9) only.
```

java Sum  100 jaja

```
    output - Plz pass 2 command line argument as numbers (0-9) only.
```

Here is my efforts but I don't now how to do it

```
    class Sum {
public static void main (String args[]){
    int a, b, c;
    a= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    b= Integer.parseInt(args [1]);
    c= a + b;

    System.out.println("Sum is= " +c);
}
```

}

Comment: Code looks ok if they are passing in arguments to your program when starting it up. So, what is the problem/error you are seeing? How would you know the difference between a float and a double? int is easy because it has no decimal place.

Comment: yeah code is ok but its not correct, I have just put this code for my efforts. Suppose user gives the double value the ? Here we cant use the if else and switch case.
Yes exactly How would I know the difference between a float and double?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for arbitrary precision, and you could use a regular expression to match numbers. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2 || !args[0].matches("\\d+[.\\d+]*")
            || !args[1].matches("\\d+[.\\d+]*")) {
        System.out.println("Plz pass 2 command line argument as numbers (0-9) only");
        return;
    }
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(args[0]);
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(args[1]);
    BigDecimal c = a.add(b);
    System.out.println("Sum is " + c);
}
```

Comment: java Sum 5.000 -5.000 yields 0.000. If the user just wants a single 0 he could use if (c.intValue() == 0) c = BigDecimal.ZERO; before the println.

Comment: Thanks but I have one problem if user gives one int value and second is string then it throws the NumberFormateException. 
java Sum 12 abc
expected outout is : Plz pass 2 command line argument as numbers (0-9) only.

Comment: @GuruJi you could try having a `try/catch` around the `BigDecimal` constructors and print appropriate messages.

Comment: @GuruJi Add the `if` checks with the [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) example I provided.